# How to fix: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (28, 28)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to input my own image into the mnist model

```py
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
model.predict(gray)
```

gray is an image that is of shape (28,28) but I am getting an error stating that the model expects 3 dimensions even though the input shape is (28,28).

The code works if I do gray.reshape(1,28,28) but I don't know why that works or if that is even the correct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model` instance expects a batch of images. This is specified on this line:

```
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
```

When you specify the `input_shape=(28, 28)`, you are basically telling Tensorflow that you will receive a batch of inputs, where each element in the batch will have shape `28 x 28`. So, when you add your image, make sure to expand its dimensions:

```
gray = np.expand_dims(gray, axis=0)
```

Then, you can safely do:

```
model.predict(gray)
```

---

Besides, in this particular case you are fine using `np.reshape`. However, that method serves a different purpose so I would stick to `np.expand_dims`. Here is proof to see that they are equal:

```
X = np.random.rand(28, 28)
np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.expand_dims(X, axis=0), np.reshape(X (1, 28, 28)))
# The assert passes
```

Comment: does gray.reshape(1,28,28) do the same thing?